# How to move virtual listView items up and down?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am unable to move the items in my listview. Its contents are virtual.

I tried listview.selectedItems but it does not work so I tried listview.SelectedIndices and got an error about Index not being declared with int.
I am not sure if I am going about this the wrong way but Index seems to be the issue. This Method worked when I tried it without a virtual listview, but I need it to work with my virtual listview. Any helpful tips?

```
private void ListView_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Log thisLog = myLogs[e.ItemIndex];
            e.Item = new ListViewItem(
                                      new string[]
                                      {
                                        thisLog.displayIndex.ToString(),
                                        thisLog.date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                                        thisLog.GetCode(),
                                        thisLog.GetThreadName(),
                                        thisLog.GetMessage()
                                      })
                     {
                        Tag = thisLog,
                        ForeColor = (thisLog.GetType() == 'E') ? Program.accentColor1 : Color.Black,
                        BackColor = (thisLog.GetType() == 'D') ? Program.accentColor2 : Color.White
                     };
        }







private void UpRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    downRB.Checked = !upRB.Checked;
}

private void DownRB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    upRB.Checked = !downRB.Checked;

}

private void MoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (moveTB.Text != null)
    {
        int dir;
        int amount;
        try
        {

            dir = upRB.Checked ? -1 : 1;
            amount = int.Parse(moveTB.Text) * dir;

            bool valid = listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0
        && ((amount > 0 && (listView.SelectedIndices[listView.SelectedIndices.Count - 1] < listView.Items.Count - amount))
        || (amount < 0 && (listView.SelectedIndices[0] > -amount)));

            if (valid)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedIndices)
                {
                    int index = item.Index + amount;
                    Program.AddBefore((Log)item.Tag, (Log)listView.Items[item.Index - 1].Tag, (Log)listView.Items[index].Tag);
                    listView.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                    listView.Items.Insert(index, item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input or selected logs.");
        }
    }
}

private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This operation cannot be undone.", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedIndices)
            {
                Program.Remove((Log)item.Tag, (Log)listView.Items[item.Index - 1].Tag);
                listView.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mong Zhu, I added the code.

Comment: Do you have an event handler for `listView`'s `RetrieveVirtualItem` event? If so, please post it.

Comment: Just posted it.

Comment: This: `foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedIndices)` is invalid. It doesn't throw right away just because those are objects. Change it in `foreach (var item in listView1.SelectedIndices)` to see what you using there. + Don't ever try change the collection you're iterating. Collect the Indexes and use that collection as the iterator's source (so that the collection you're iterating won't change, compromising the whole procedure).

Comment: In virtual mode, a list view doesn't keep a copy of the data it displays. It fires `RetrieveVirtualItem` to ask you for the data to display, which you're providing. All you have to do to move items is modify your data structure (`myLogs`) and let the event handler take care of the rest. This code is just moving around placeholders.

Comment: So am I changing what is in my retrieveVirtualItem or moveButton_click?

Comment: When I enter  the foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedIndices), I am getting errors based on item.Index.

Comment: Change `MoveButton_Click` to move the items within `myLog`. And change `Delete_Click` to remove items and subtract from `listView.VirtualListSize`. Hopefully, `myLogs` is a list and not an array.